# Does Fatal and/or Deadly apply when attacking a critical hit-immune target?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, critical-hit, immunities, traits

Critical hit [immunity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=343) specifies

> Immunity to critical hits works a little differently. When a creature immune to critical hits is critically hit by a Strike or other attack that deals damage, **it takes normal damage instead of double damage. This does not make it immune to any other critical success effects** of other actions that have the attack trait (such as Grapple and Shove).

I find it unclear whether the [Deadly](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=174)/[Fatal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=178) weapon traits, which are patently *not* doubling the damage, are nonetheless canceled or if they qualify as 'other critical success effects'.

Is there any rules text to clarify this?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180396/when-extra-damage-dice-are-listed-in-a-critical-effect-do-they-apply-to-crit-im) (possible dupe but I'm not sure)

Comment: I don't think I'd call this a dupe, but more of a specific subset of the other question.

Comment: That's what I was thinking when I posted it, but figured it was worth noting in case the community at large disagreed. The most Up'd answer here contradicts the answer in the other question, so I'm curious if they both land on an answer that agrees with each other or if the community sees the situations as different enough to have different answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

From the 4th edition Core Rulebook [clarifications](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq):

> ### How do extra critical effects work on a creature immune to critical hits?
>
> Immunity to critical hits reads “When a creature immune to critical hits is critically hit by a Strike or other attack that deals damage, it takes normal damage instead of double damage.” This means what it says: The attack deals normal damage instead of double damage. Other effects specific to a critical hit still occur, **such as critical specialization effects and extra damage dice from traits like deadly and fatal**.

Increasing the damage die on a critical hit would also be included as a critical hit effect outside of doubling damage.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes it does

Immunity to critical hits means that you take normal damage **instead of double damage**. It does not make you immune to any other critical success effects. Fatal and Deadly both are traits that result in **other critical success effects**, as indicated by the critical success effects described in their write ups. The Fatal trait states:

> **On a critical hit**, the weapon’s damage die increases (...)

The Deadly trait states:

> **On a critical hit**, the weapon adds a weapon damage die (...)

Neither deals **double damage**, even if these other critical success effects happen to deal additional damage. Therefore, immunity to critical hits does not make you immune to them.

To be immune to these traits, you would need to have explicit immunity to that trait, p. 451 core rules:

> If you have immunity to effects with a certain trait ([...]), you are unaffected by effects with that trait.

Comment: Just to add an example, you're saying that a Striking Fatal d10 weapon would deal 3d10 damage on a critical hit? And a Striking d8 Deadly d10 weapon would deal 2d8+1d10 damage? You literally just remove the (*)x2 from the weapon damage dice (and ability score, etc) section?

Comment: @Ifusaso Yes, you just remove the double damage die from the critical, as the text says. The other critical success effects still damage you normally.

Comment: I posted a separate answer. I think this answer's primary flaw is that it overreads "double damage" without analyzing the context of the rest of the sentence. Not that it's a bad answer (so I've not downvoted it), but I do think it's incorrect.